# Async/Await in useEffect(): how to get useState() value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have the following code snippet. Why is my limit always 0 in my `fetchData`? If I were to `console.log(limit)` outside of this function it has the correct number. Also If I dont use `useState` but a variable instead `let limit = 0;` then it works as expected

I also added limit as a dependency in useEffect but it just keeps triggering the function

```
  const [currentData, setData] = useState([]);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(0);

const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log(limit);
    const { data } = await axios.post(endpoint, {
      limit: limit,
    });
    setData((state) => [...state, ...data]);
    setLimit((limit) => limit + 50);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    window.addEventListener(`scroll`, (e) => {
      if (bottomOfPage) {
        fetchData();
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an empty dependency array `[]` to `useEffect`, the effect runs **only once on the initial render**:

> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect
> will always have their initial values.
>
> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

[useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

The initial state of `limit` is `0` as defined in your `useState` call. Adding `limit` as a dependency will cause the effect to run every time `limit` changes.

Comment: Yes I understand, in this case on mount fetchData() will run, this will change the limit to 50 then it will cause fetchData() to keep re-running and get stuck in a loop

Comment: @Freddy. — Then you need to figure out under what change in conditions `fetch` should be called again, and what should change those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around your issue is to wrap the `fetchData` method in a `useCallback` while passing the `limit` variable to the dependency array.

You can then pass the function to the dependency array of useEffect and also return a function from inside of useEffect that removes event listeners with outdated references.

You should also add a loading variable so that the fetchData function doesn't get called multiple times while the user is scrolling to the bottom:

```js
const [currentData, setData] = useState([]);
const [limit, setLimit] = useState(0);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(limit);
    // Prevent multiple endpoint calls when scrolling near the end with a loading state
    if (loading) {
        return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    const { data } = await axios.post(endpoint, { limit });
    setData((state) => [...state, ...data]);
    setLimit((limit) => limit + 50);
    setLoading(false);
}, [limit, loading]);

// Make the initial request on the first render only
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);

// Whenever the fetchData function changes update the event listener
useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = (e) => {
        if (bottomOfPage) {
            fetchData();
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener(`scroll`, onScroll);

    // On unmount ask it to remove the listener
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
}, [fetchData]);
```